# Can bundler show me which gems in Gemfile have newer versions (eg. dry-run of bundle update)

Tags: ruby, bundler

Is there a way to run [bundle update](http://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html) in pretend mode, similar to the -p (pretend) flag for Rails generators or cap's -n (dry-run) flag?

I'm imagining something like:

```
$> bundle update -p
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
The following gems have updated versions:
...
list of gems
...
```

Comment: I was searching for something like that just a few days ago too, but so far no luck.  Hopefully they'll something like soon if it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Bundler 1.1 introduced a new 'outdated' feature, which is exactly what I was looking for. Pat Shaughnessy has a great [write-up](http://patshaughnessy.net/2011/11/5/besides-being-faster-what-else-is-new-in-bundler-1-1) on the new features. In his words, `bundle outdated`:

> displays the gems it would download and install, but without actually
>   doing it. This gives me the freedom to inspect the list and update
>   just the gems I would like to.

This should make it a snap to see what gems are due for an update without actually modifying your source and local gems. Thanks Bundler!

Comment: It seems like `bundle outdated` will show newer versions of gems, but won't take into account the version limits specified in your `Gemfile`, so it may not display the same results as a full update. For example, I have `gem 'rails', '~> 3.1.3'` specified in my Gemfile, and `bundle update rails` works as expected, but `bundle outdated` shows `* rails (3.2.8 > 3.1.3)`.

Comment: @zole, that can be seen as either an advantage or disadvantage. For example, I usually specify the gem versions for every gem, so `bundle outdated` would be useless for me if it looked at those versions. But for someone like you who only limits some gems' versions, you would be better off with version checking. So I think an optional argument would be the solution for both our cases.

Comment: Looks like the `--strict` option was added in version bundler v1.5. I have just tried it out and it seems to work like @zole was expecting. Source: http://bundler.io/v1.7/bundle_outdated.html

Comment: sometimes even a gem is up to date, it can be no longer in active development(abandoned project). is there any way to list down release dates of the gems?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ bundle update
$ git diff Gemfile.lock
$ git checkout Gemfile.lock
```

Comment: This is nowhere near an answer to the question. OP asks about "bundler"; this answer provides a hacky solution that has nothing to do with bundler's functionality.

Comment: Your comment is bad. It misses both the point - no, bundler has no such comment, but here's a workaround - and the context - this answer was written before `bundle outdated` or any similar commands were around.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking specifically for how to only show the outdated gems that are in my gemfile.  Looks like this does it: `bundle outdated --only-explicit`

That will 'Only list gems specified in your Gemfile, not their dependencies'

Source: https://bundler.io/man/bundle-outdated.1.html

Hopefully this is helpful for someone else.