# Is there a way to get notifications for new gems with Bundler?

Tags: ruby

I'm using Bundler for the gem dependency management.

Is there a way to get a notification when a new gem of a gem specified in `Gemfile` available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to "[Can bundler show me which gems in Gemfile have newer versions (eg. dry-run of bundle update)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696932/can-bundler-show-me-which-gems-in-gemfile-have-newer-versions-eg-dry-run-of-bun)" topic - there is no direct way to do it.

As a workaround if you use version controll just invoke `bundler update` print diff of `Gemfile.lock` (against version from repo) and revert it back.

**Update Jun 2012**: as of bundler 1.1 there is new command option `bundle outdated` - it prints nicely what are installed and latest versions of gems:

```
$ bundle outdated
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......

Outdated gems included in the bundle:
  * multi_json (1.3.6 > 1.1.0)
  * activesupport (3.2.6 > 3.2.1)
  * activemodel (3.2.6 > 3.2.1)
  * journey (1.0.4 > 1.0.3)
...
```

Thanks Shaun.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the `diff` method, which seems handy.

Comment: There is now the `bundle outdated` command: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10724769/99266

Answer (score 5):

While I don't think there's a way to directly monitor your `Gemfile`, RubyGems' website lets you subscribe to multiple gems if you create an account and log in. Then you could subscribe to the RSS feed (assuming you use an RSS reader) and know every time a new version comes out.

Answer (score 3):

The command `bundle outdated` will tell you which gems can updated in your bundle. For more information on how to use the command take a look at the help command `bundle --help outdated`

More documentation on the command: http://gembundler.com/v1.1/bundle_outdated.html

Answer (score -1):

I sketched out one way to implement notifications, here: http://www.masonsimon.com/idea-email-notification-of-new-gem-versions-i. I hope to have time for it soon, but if anyone else wants to implement it first, feel free :)