# Bundler: How to check if Gems are up to date

Tags: ruby, bundler

Using Bundler, is there a way to check if there are newer gems available than the versions specified in the Gemfile? In other words, is there a way to check if my gems are up to date without actually updating?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can bundler show me which gems in Gemfile have newer versions (eg. dry-run of bundle update)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696932/can-bundler-show-me-which-gems-in-gemfile-have-newer-versions-eg-dry-run-of-bun)

Answer (score 32):

List installed gems with newer versions available

```
$ bundle outdated [GEM] [--local] [--pre] [--source]
```

Options:

`--local`: Do not attempt to fetch gems remotely and use the gem cache instead

`--pre`: Check for newer pre-release gems

`--source`: Check against a specific source

Source: http://bundler.io/v1.3/bundle_outdated.html

Comment: sometimes even a gem is up to date, it can be no longer in active development(abandoned project). is there any way to list down release dates of the gems?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean just see if an update is necessary (w/o actually updating), you might have to specify in your Gemfile to use some repo source for comparison, like:

`gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"`

or specify a specific version to compare against with `:version => ...`

Then run `bundle check` and it'll list all gems that are out of date.

**EDIT** - I guess it depends on what's meant by up to date.

Comment: @coreyward perhaps - care to explain?

Comment: You had explained how to update them, not how to check if they needed an update. I've removed the downvote since this your edits are in the spirit of the question (though a more explicit note about `bundle check` just checking dependencies might be helpful).

Comment: yup, after re-reading my own answer and the question it seemed quite off topic - thanks.