# How can you preview the updates that a "Bundle Update" will make?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, bundler

Sometimes I want to run bundle update but only to see which gems need updating. I don't necessarily want to deal with the issues associated with updating all of them but I want to do a quick check to see what's the state of the art.

Is there a way to simply get Bundler to list the gems that need to be updated together (ideally) with the version I'm currently running and what's the latest and greatest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried this:

```
> gem install bundle_outdated
> bundle-outdated
Finding outdated gems..

Newer versions found for:
  rails (3.1.0 > 3.0.0)
  haml (3.1.2 > 3.0.0)
  rspec-rails (2.6.1 > 2.0.1)

Lock bundle to these versions by putting the following in your Gemfile:
  gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
  gem 'haml', '3.1.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'

You may try to update non-specific dependencies via:
  $ bundle update haml rspec-rails

Handwaving specifications:
  haml: >= 3.0.0
  rspec-rails: >= 2.0.1
```

**Another alternative:**

```
> gem install gem-outdated
> gem outdated
```

Comment: Very helpful - bundle-outdated looks like what I'm after, ty

Comment: Be very careful before doing what this answer suggests. Firstly; bundle outdated does not consider version dependency requirements. Meaning it will show everything as new even if you have a specific version for your gem in your Gemfile. Secondly; **bundle update gemname** command updates all dependencies of the gem. Meaning you may end up with a new rails version if "gemname" has dependency  on rails. (which haml does, which is given in the example). Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 16):

There is now a way to do this directly with bundler. You do not need to install any extra gems.

```
bundle outdated
```

will return something like this

```
Outdated gems included in the bundle:
  * acts-as-taggable-on (2.4.1 > 2.3.3)
  * addressable (2.3.4 > 2.3.3)
  * arel (4.0.0 > 3.0.2)
  * better_errors (0.8.0 > 0.7.2)
  * builder (3.2.0 > 3.0.4)
  * capybara (2.1.0 > 2.0.3)
  * chunky_png (1.2.8 > 1.2.7)
  * codemirror-rails (3.12 > 3.02)
  * coffee-rails (4.0.0 > 3.2.2)
  .....
```

Answer (score 5):

Since google searches hit this page and the answers provided have some points that needs attention, i will add another answer.

If you want to see which updates are released for your gems, taking "**version dependency requirements** in your Gemfile" into account, use:

```
bundle outdated --strict
```

If you don't want to take version dependency into account, simply use `bundle outdated` as specified in other answers.

Secondly, if you want to update a specific gem, use:

```
bundle update --source gemname
```

`bundle update gemname` updates the gem and all its dependencies which may leave you in a mess (even rails gets updated by using `bundle update haml`).

Answer (score 0):

There's not a way to do this directly with bundler, but so long as you're using a VCS then you can always revert the Gemfile.lock to revert the changes make by update, or diff the file to see what changes have been made. See this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4696932/can-bundler-show-me-which-gems-in-gemfile-have-newer-versions-eg-dry-run-of-bun)

Answer (score 0):

List installed gems with newer versions available:

```
bundle outdated
```

Only list gems specified in your Gemfile, not their dependencies.

```
bundle outdated --only-explicit
```